# Formula Field On a Case object

Tags: formula, case, formula-field

I have a case object and two other objects associated to it(associates and stores)

I want to design a formula field, such that when an associate ldapid field gets the input, then the store number should be popped up in the formula field.

Associate is detail of Store object.

I tried an `IF` condition , but it didn't work.

Comment: Please explain how all of the objects you mentioned are related. Does `Case` have a lookup field to `Associate__c`? Does `Associate__c` have a lookup field to `Store`? Also, on which object are you trying to create this formula (is it `Case`)? Can you provide the formula that isn't working?

Comment: Hello Derek, I first designed a lookup field with associate name and designed a formula field with store number, both on the case object. Later i figured that my approach was wrong for my configuration. There would be a sync to salesforce case from intercom messages and the associates type in their LDAP ID instead of their name. So , when the associate LDAP ID field is filled up with the information, then the formula is supposed to extended to associate name and store number. Store is master and associate is child. does this make sense?